# Connecting Remote Cache Manager to Embedded Cache Manager

Tags: infinispan

Infinispan community,
I am trying to deploy Embedded Cache Manager on each node in the network then creating a Remote Cache Manager that can connect to these Embedded ones. I didn't find where to configure the port of communication for the embedded cache manager so I can connect to using the Remote Cache Manager.
Help !!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-playground-embedded-hotrod which shows how to wrap a Hot Rod server around an embedded instance.